# How to set the style on SVG retrieved from the geojson file with Leaflet?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet

I was able to display the map from the geojson file.
But CSS I wrote and the actual display doesn't match like img below.

[image: Developer tool display]

I wrote CSS like below.
I have to set the overflow as visible.

```
body, #map {
   overflow: visible;
   zoom: 100%;
   width: 1500px;
   height: 1000px;
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
}
```

The actual style of SVG is below.

```
<body>
<div id="map" class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim" tabindex="0" style="position: relative;"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane"></div><div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane">
<svg pointer-events="none" width="1800" height="1200" viewBox="-150 -100 1800 1200" style="transform: translate3d(-150px, -100px, 0px);">
<g>~~~</g>
</svg>~~~
```

What makes width=1800 and height=1200 although I set width=1500 and height=1000?
The code for getting data from the geojson file is below.

```
$.getJSON("japan.geojson", function(data) {
    let geojsonback = L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    },
    });
    geojsonback.addTo(map);
    });
```

I would like to match atcual style of SVG and CSS I wrote.

I have already tried adding style like below but it didn't work well.

```
const myPolygonStyle={
    "width":1500,
    "viewBox":"0 0 1500 1000"
}
$.getJSON("japan.geojson", function(data) {
    let geojsonback = L.geoJson(data, {
        style:myPolygonStyle,
        onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                    },
    });
    geojsonback.addTo(map);
    console.log(geojsonback)
    });
```

Comment: Please add a demo: https://leafletjs.com/edit.html

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't work.
I would like to change i.x, i.y, t.min.x, and t.min.y in CSS of svg[Attributes Style].
How should I do?
Below is the source code of leaflet.js.
`this._svgSize=i,e.setAttribute("width",i.x),e.setAttribute("height",i.y)),Z(e,t.min),e.setAttribute("viewBox",[t.min.x,t.min.y,i.x,i.y]`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem by adding the below.
Thank you.

```
let map = L.map("map",{
    renderer: L.svg({
    padding:0
})
```